# Constrain mouse to guest in VMWare Workstation 15 Player

Tags: vmware

With VMWare Tools installed, the mouse cursor can freely enter and exit the guest OS. Is there a setting to disable this? I would like the cursor to be constrained to the guest like it typically is when VMWare Tools is not installed. Also, can I assign a hotkey to this setting?

Host and guest are both running Windows 10. I am using VMWare Workstation 15 Player.

Comment: You could try attaching the device to the VM itself but I suspect VMWare didn't bother to support that.  But unless you hit the shortcut to escape the VM the mouse should stay associated with the VM.

Comment: Could one issue be that I am running the "free" player? Does the paid version have more settings that can be configured?